# Changing the layer name in Legend for QGIS Print Layout with Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer, legend

My aim is to change the layer's name only within the legend - I want to leave the layer itself untouched. I tried multiple variants of X.setName(), both on the vector layer item, the map layer and the LayerTreeLayer and so on, via the model - All of that also changes the layer's name outside the legend, which is not what I want.

I found that within the Print Layout editor, there is actually a way to achieve this - you can click on the legend item, select the one you want to rename, "edit selected item properties", and then just enter the new label text. But how can I do this from code?

This is my code so far, using a rename of the base layer which is what I want to avoid.

```py
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Legend")

# vector_layer.setName("Layer Name in Legend")  # change item name in legend
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)  # separates the layout's legend from the project's

legend.setLinkedMap(map)
legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(235, 36, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

I am working in QGIS 3.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my previous answer was still just a workaround, and if I edited the legend afterwards, it would realize as much and reset itself. Alas, here is the actual solution, with heavy inspiration from the [QGIS API on QgisLayoutItemLegend](https://api.qgis.org/api/qgslayoutitemlegend_8cpp_source.html):

```py
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)

for tr in legend.model().rootGroup().children():
    if tr.name() == layer_name:
        tr.setCustomProperty("legend/title-label", "new name in legend")

layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
```

That's it. That is all you actually had to do. No need to worry about the legend being drawn first either.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you already got a working solution, but here is another approach- passing the layer tree layer object, the index of the root node and the desired label as a string to the [setLegendNodeUserLabel()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerLegendUtils.html#a9dc579bf7c18749d528a087df91856ca) method of the `QgsMapLayerLegendUtils` class.

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_Name_In_Project')[0]
lyr_tree_lyr = legend.model().rootGroup().findLayer(layer.id())
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
QgsMapLayerLegendUtils.setLegendNodeUserLabel(lyr_tree_lyr, 0, 'Label name you want in layout legend')
legend.model().refreshLayerLegend(lyr_tree_lyr)
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but it did not work for me - If you tried it and it did work, I suspect the difference is in the symbology. My layer is a graduated line layer, and index 0 addresses the first of the symbol classes, instead of the layer itself. Maybe it works for a single fill layer, but it is not a viable option for my case.

Answer (score 2):

(Hack-ish Workaround - Proper Solution in the Accepted Answer)

*After trying it out for a few hours, I finally figured it out. I was on the right path with QgsLayerTreeLayer, however, I was editing the wrong object - basically, still the vector layer itself rather than the legend.*

*First, ensure that the layout has actually been generated - rather than continuing to work with the created legend item, access the item within the layout:*

```py
legend_item = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
```

*(Do comment if there's a better way to get the legend, particularly since there's only one.)*

```py
lyr = legend_item.model().rootGroup().findLayer(vector_layer)  # switch from QgsVectorLayer to QgsLayerTreeLayer
lyr.setUseLayerName(False)  # Make the legend use a name different from the layer's
```

*Here's the really important part: We don't want to work with the layer objects saved above - We want those within the* legend.

```py
tree_layers = legend_item.model().rootGroup().children()  # get the legend's layer tree
for tr in tree_layers:
    if tr.name() == layer_name: # ensure you have the correct child node
        tr.setName("New Name")  # set the child node's new name
legend_item.updateLegend()  # Update the QgsLayerTreeModel
```